# How to keep DropDownList values between a server call in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewstate, html.dropdownlistfor

I have an **ASP.NET MVC3** application. I have the following `ViewModel`:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Month {get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Years
    {
       get
       {
           return Enumerable.Range(2000, DateTime.Now.Year - 2000).Select(x => new SelectListItem
           {
               Value = x.ToString(),
               Text = x.ToString()
           });
       }
    } 
}
```

And the following `View`:

```
@model MyNamespace.MyViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.Year, 
    new SelectList(Model.Years, "Value", "Text"),
    "-- select year --"
)

@Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.Month, 
    Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),
    "-- select month --"
)
```

I fill the `DropDownList` for `Month` with a `jQuery` function that is triggered `onchange` from the `DropDownList` for `Year`, which works perfectly. When the form is posted to the server and then the view is rendered back I want to keep the values in the 'Month' DropDownList as it happens correctly for `Year`. Therefore I tried (besides the jQuery script):

```
public class MyViewModel
 {
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Month {get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Months
    {
        get
        {
            if(Year != null)
            {
               return Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => new SelectListItem
               {
                  Value = x.ToString(),
                  Text = x.ToString()
               });
            }
        }
    }
```

And in the `View`:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(
            x => x.Month, 
       new SelectList(Model.Months, "Value", "Text"),
        "-- select month --"
    )
```

I left Years out of the code to make things shorter. This code throws a `NullReferenceException` at the first run because the `IEnumerable` is empty. how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Just a small question, why are you bothering to populate months based off of year's change event?  Just curious since it would seem you'd want to populate both at the same time.

Comment: @IyaTaisho, I am creating an application to display stats and I also populate days with the same logic. I want also to hinder to the user the option to select a month  without selecting the year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to repopulate the month list in your action.
The POST is stateless is not like asp.net webforms. 
Just do something like this in your code:

```
public ViewResult MyAction(MyViewModel model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       //.. do your stuff ...
       //return redirect to index if everything went ok
   }

   //something went wrong return the model
   model.Years = new SelectList(/* code to populate years */, "Value", "Text", Model.Year);
   model.Months = new SelectList(/* code to populate months */, "Value", "Text",  Model.Month);
}
```

As a side note I prefer to use `SelectList` instead of `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` beacuse I can set the default value in the controller (a better fit for the controller responsibility in my opinion) and not in the View.

Comment: thanks, however how may you solve the NullReferenceException issue in the View when Months is empty?

Comment: As stated in my answer you have to repopulate the months in the action otherwise it will always be null. the view do not persist any state between post call.